# How do I display the altitude of the user in swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, core-location

I'm trying to build an app that displays the altitude of the user, but xCode says that CLLocation doesn't have member 'altitude'. The code I'm using is

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) { self.Altitude.text = String(locations.altitude)}
```

Comment: Locations is an array of locations and arrays don't have a property `altitude`. You must first get one of the location elements out of the array like `locations[0].altitude`

Answer (score 1):

Xcode does not say "CLLocation" has no member 'altitude'" but "[CLLocation] has no member 'altitude'".

`locations` is an array of `CLLocation` objects and (as it is an array) does not have a property named `altitude`.

What you need to do is extract one value from the array and use that to access the altitude.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
  guard let altitude = locations.last?.altitude else { return }
  self.Altitude.text = String(altitude)
}
```

Since this is a user facing string you should format it properly using a [`LengthFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/lengthformatter).

A small style note: variable names (like `self.Altitude` should be lowercased, only types are PascalCase).

Comment: Why ".last"? How would I know this?

Comment: Because it’s the most recent location and that (usually) the one you want to work with.

Comment: I see. Anyhow, you can also use the manager’s location (which is what I ended up doing, as I like knowing how the code I use works)

Comment: Well, it's all in the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager Now you also know how the above code works ;)

Comment: For specific settings using the `location` property can also give you old data: ```It is always a good idea to check the timestamp of the location stored in this property. If the receiver is currently gathering location data, but the minimum distance filter is large, the returned location might be relatively old. If it is, you can stop the receiver and start it again to force an update.``` from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423687-location

Comment: But isn't `didUpdateLocations` called on a location change? How then can `manager.location!` have anything but the latest location?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can get Altitude from reverse geocoding in swift for this you can use locationManager and locationManager didUpdateLocations method. 

Step 1: Add below Code in ViewdidLoad method:- 

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.headingFilter = 1
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()


Step 2: Use didUpdateLocations Method:- 

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
 guard let altitude = locations.last?.altitude else { return }
}
```